# Algorithm for in-place calculation of the sorting permutation?

Tags: sorting

A sorting algorithm is in-place if it requires only O(1) more memory than the data being sorted.

Given an array of n integers x[0]...x[n-1], the *sorting permutation* of this array is another array s[0]...s[n-1] of log_2(n)-bit unique integers such that x[s[0]]...x[s[n-1]] is a sorted array.

The obvious way to compute the sorting permutation is to make an array of tuples (x[i],i) sort it on the first coordinate of the tuple, then take the second coordinate projection.  However in the worst case without duplicates where the elements being sorted are log_2(n) bits long this will double the memory requirements, even if the sort is an in-place sort.

Question:

> What in-place algorithms exist to calculate the sorting permutation? 
>   Only the permutation is needed, not the sorted data -- they can be
>   destroyed during the sorting.

One approach is to use an LSB-first radix sort.  After each of the log_2(n) passes one bit of every entry can be destroyed (since it won't be needed anymore).  This bit can be used to encode the permutation incrementally, as the sorting proceeds.  When you're done you need to decode this "sorting trace" which is tricky and convoluted, but possible.  Also radix sort is not automatically an in-place sort, so there is additional complexity there.

I'm mainly looking for a foothold in the literature on this.  Searches for "sorting permutation" have not been too helpful.  Is there a better search term?  Maybe even a survey paper?

I'm also interested in approaches based on sorting algorithms that are easy to implement in the extrenal memory model -- ideally a merge sort.  Unfortunately with comparison-based sorts you don't get the "this bit can be thrown away" guarantee that arises automatically from radix sorts.

If it matters, I actually only need to find all indexes of duplicate entries in the original array, but I believe this is worst-case asymptotically no easier than sorting.  Happy to be corrected if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Edit: needs to be O(n log n) time complexity, or very very close to it.  The sort does not need to be a stable sort.

Comment: "sort s[] according to x[]" is equivalent to sorting (x,s) tuples.

Comment: Sort s[] according to x[] -> only changes s[], leaving x[] unchanged. To be clear, in the process of sorting or finding duplicates, it's OK to destroy what is in x[] and replace the data values with indices?

Comment: only changes s[], leaving x[] unchanged -> oh, okay, I see what you mean; yeah, that's not the same thing (but still the same 2x amount of memory).

Comment: To be clear, in the process of sorting or finding duplicates, it's OK to destroy what is in x[] and replace the data values with indices? -> yes, absolutely.  In fact I think you have to, otherwise there's no room for the result (while still being in-place).

Comment: You could implement something similar to insertion sort: non duplicates would be deleted by shifting a portion of x[] left. Each duplicate would be deleted by shifting a portion of x[] right to make room for an index at the front of the shifted portion of x[]. This would be a O(n^2) process, so not efficient for a large array, but it is in place.

Comment: Thanks @rcgldr, I should have mentioned that I'm looking for a O(n log n) sorting algorithm.

Comment: So the sorting permutation of the array `[24,11,87,16,12]` would be `[1,4,3,0,2]`? The problem you're going to run into doing this in-place is that you lose position information when you move an item. I can think of an O(n^2) solution, but no O(n log n) solution comes to mind.